# List all files with specified selinux context

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, selinux, libvirt

How do I list all the files with specific selinux context such as - 
'system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c332,c575' etc ??

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` with the `-context` predicate. See the `find(1)` man page for details.